# Read SD card without a file system

Tags: pic, spi, sd, fat

I design a DAQ to collect data from different sensors. The data are written on an SD card by a microcontroller, [dsPIC33FJ256GP710A](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en546064). The data are stored without a file system for speed reasons. Now I need to read the data acquired, store it on the SD card, with the PC. Are there programs for Windows that allow to convert the data on the SD card without the file system, sector by sector, in a txt or other type of file?

---

Thanks for the answers. I tried to use RawCopy64 because my OS is 64 bit, but this function allows me to copy files only between [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) disks. This is not what I want.

[image]

Are there other parameters for this function that allow to read data from an SD card without a file system?

Comment: Why not just read from the raw device?

Comment: You appear to be using rawcopy v 1.0.0.6. The copy I found was v 1.3.3. Did you use the link in my answer?  I used it to copy sector 0 on a volume marked RAW in the disk manager (I did a low level format first) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux there is the [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) command for raw device access. For Windows you can google for some tools providing the same functionality using the "dd for Windows" query. There are plenty of results, so select one that is the most suitable to your needs.

Comment: A `dd` implementation exists for windows too.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the contents of the SD card into a Windows file, try using **rawcopy** or **rawcopy64** [from here](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) (it's listed under "Small command line utilities").  rawcopy is patterned after the Unix dd command.  I just tried it to copy the first sector 0 on an 8 GB card using:

```
rawcopy 512 \\.\F: foo
```

where the SD card was in drive F and foo is the filename and it seemed to work fine.  You have to run it from the Command Prompt.  For syntax, type "rawcopy /help" and it will give you this screen:

[image]